# What's the meaning of やっていける or いける?

Tags: grammar, words, subsidiary-verbs

The sentence in question:
しかし、子育てに親が専念できる環境になってきたので、親がおんぶをしなくてもだっこだけでもやっていける。

For full context:
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0521.html?utm_int=news_contents_tokushu_004

my attempt at translation:
"However, because the circumstance has developed that towards child-raising, the adult can undivided attention, it is okay for the adult to not do the piggyback and do only with the babysling."

I used the meaning of the second entry here https://jisho.org/search/ikeru because it kind of worked, but in the end I was just guessing because I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 2):

`いける`(`行ける`) is derived from the  potential form of `行く` (to go) so literally can be thought of as “can go” but actual meaning is closer to “possible/doable”. There are also related meanings of “good” (as in taste or look) or “goes/fits well (with something)”.

As @Chocolate mentions, `やっていける` means something along the lines of “get by/along”, “manage”, or “doing enough”. You can get a feel for it by going through the examples on [ALC/Eijiro](https://eow.alc.co.jp/sp/search.html?q=%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B&pg=1). See also [やっていく](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E9%81%A3%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F)

So your translation is good, I’d probably just rephrase it slightly, e.g.

“the parents can now get away with using just the sling and do not have to piggyback”

Comment: その「やっていける」は、生活していける・暮らしていける、みたいな意味です。。

Comment: @Chocolate thanks, edited; I hope it’s better now